# App Crashes after Project and Scheme Renames Xcode 8 Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After renaming my Xcode project, scheme, and target, my app crashes at the App Delegate when running in simulator. It should be noted that the app could be run successfully, without any errors, prior to the rename. I have attempted all manner of fixes including editing the project.pbxproj file, all to no avail. The app crashes with an "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)" error at Thread 1 main.

Any assistance solving the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you retrieve and post your crash log?